# NSCalendarDayChanged is posting without the day changing

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

The following code in app delegate is supposed to add a new assignment to the assignments array **once daily**. The problem is, every time the app is opened a new assignment is added even if the day hasn't changed. It seems like the NSCalendarDayChanged is posting every time the app is opened.

```
var assignments = [Assignment]()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if let _ = loadHW(){
        assignments = loadHW()!
    }

    if let assignment = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Assignment.ArchiveURL.path) as? [Assignment]{
        assignments = assignment
    }

    // Define identifier
    let notificationName = Notification.Name("NSNotification.Name.NSCalendarDayChanged")

    // Register to receive notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(calendarDayDidChange(notification:)), name: notificationName, object: nil)

    // Post notification
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)


    // Override point for customization after application launch.NSNotification.Name.NSCalendarDayChanged
    return true
}
func calendarDayDidChange(notification : NSNotification)
{
    let currentDate = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    let dayOfTheWeek = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian).component(.weekday, from: Date())
    print(dayOfTheWeek)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/YY"
    let convertedCurrentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
    print(convertedCurrentDate)

    //Adds an assignment based on date comparisons
    if let dates = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: SettingsViewController.datesURL.path) as? [Date] {
        print(1)
        if currentDate >= dates[0] && currentDate <= dates[1] {
            print(2)
            if let weekendHW = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: SettingsViewController.weekendURL.path) as? Bool {
                print(3)
                if(weekendHW || (!weekendHW && dayOfTheWeek != 1 && dayOfTheWeek != 7)){
                    print(4)
                    if assignments.count > 0{
                        assignments.insert(Assignment(hw: assignments[0].hw, date: convertedCurrentDate)!, at: 0)
                        print(5)
                    }else if assignments.count == 0 {
                        assignments.append(Assignment(hw: "", date: convertedCurrentDate)!)
                        print(6)
                    }
                    saveHW()
                    print("save complete")
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //adds assignment on first launch of app
    if assignments.count == 0 {
        assignments.append(Assignment(hw: "", date: convertedCurrentDate)!)
        saveHW()
    }

}
func saveHW() {
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(assignments, toFile: Assignment.ArchiveURL.path) //saves array grades to file defined in Assignment class

    if !isSuccessfulSave { //Diagnostic
        print("Save failed")
    }
}

func loadHW() -> [Assignment]? {
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Assignment.ArchiveURL.path) as? [Assignment] //gets array grades from file where saved, defined in Assignment class

}
```

What can I change to **ensure only one assignment is created per day**?

Comment: Make a note of the last time you received the notification (or use the date of the last assignment), and compare that to the current date before doing anything else?

Comment: Actually, the issue is more probably that just after adding the observer... you post a notification for that event!

Comment: Why do you unarchive the same `Assignment` object up to three times?

Comment: @jcaron TRUE! Whoops... sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not *NSCalendarDayChanged is posting*, **you** are posting the notification. Delete the line

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
```

and delete also

```
if let _ = loadHW(){
    assignments = loadHW()!
}
```

It's redundant. The following `if - let` expression does exactly the same.